# При определении одной и той же переменной в разных функциях код стопорится | Arduino c++

Tags: c++, функции, arduino

Вчера победил многозадачность в Arduino и решил не делать 4 переменные 2 из которых копия других 2. Засунул одинаковые переменные в разные функции. Заливаю... Светодиоды загорелись, но тухнуть не хотят. В чём я накосячил?

Вот код (кот):

```
int main() {

  init();

  while (1) {
    led13_ne(), led12_ne();
  }

}

void led13_ne() {
  DDRB |= B10000000;
  //init();
  unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
  const long interval = 1000;
  byte port13read = 0;
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {

    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    //currentMillis = 0;
    port13read = bitRead(PORTB, 7);

    if (port13read == 0) {
      PORTB |= B10000000;
      //port13read = 1;
    } else {
      PORTB &= ~B10000000;
      //port13read = 0;
    }

  }
}

void led12_ne() {
  DDRB |= B01000000;
  unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
  const long interval = 500;
  byte port12read = 0;
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {

    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    //currentMillis = 0;
    port12read = bitRead(PORTB, 6);

    if (port12read == 0) {
      PORTB |= B01000000;
      //port13read = 1;
    } else {
      PORTB &= ~B01000000;
      //port13read = 0;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Называть функцию "воидом" - косяк...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Я для удобства.

Comment: Это все работать не будет, так как значение, присвоенное в `previousMillis = currentMillis;` больше не используетеся. На следующей итерации `previousMillis` снова будет 0. *"и решил не делать 4 переменные "* ... и сделал две одинаковые функции с четырмя переменными в каждой.

Comment: @VTT Как ноль? Почему?? Как так то? Я не понимаю.

Comment: @Timoha_Timohavich При выходе из функции область видимости `previousMillis` заканчивается и значение теряется. При следующем вызове снова выполнится `unsigned long previousMillis = 0;`.

Comment: А вы просто без всяких функций примеры сделайте: `int a=0; for(int i=0;i<10;i++) { a=a+1; }` И `for(int i=0;i<10;i++) { int a=0; a=a+1; }`. Теперь внимательно присмотритесь. в первом случае видно, что переменная a меняется, потому что ей один раз присвоили 0, а потом увеличивают 10 раз. Результат - a=10; Во втором варианте, переменной a 10 раз присваивают 0, а потом прибавляют 1. и конечно от того что 0+1 выполнен 10 раз ответ всегда будет 1, а не 10. У вас в коде то же самое. Только надо заметить что при выходе из функции значение локальной переменной всегда теряется

Comment: VTT @Mike спасибо) Наверное, если бы я правильно гуглил, то решил бы свою проблему и без вопроса. Но всё ровно, может вопрос понадобится кому нибудь...

Answer (score 0):

Переменная `previousMillis` должна быть или глобальной:

```
  unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
  void led13_ne() {
     ...
  }
```

или статичной:

```
  void led13_ne() {
     static unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
     ...
  }
```

Тогда она будет обнуляться только при рестарте микроконтроллера.
А сейчас она обнуляется при каждом вызове функции.

Comment: Зачем?) В функциях реализованны задержки, но в отличии от `_delay_ms(250);` они не остановят работу других функций наглухо.

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Исправил ответ.